# Make a popup when page size decrease in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

currently I am working on WPF application.In a page I have two parts (e.g. part1 | Part2).In part1 I have list of items and when I select any of the item I will get detail of that item in part2.When I decrease the size of the window page I want that details part to be pop up.How can I achieve that ? Please help!

Comment: Is there any particular issue you are experiencing while implementing this behavior? Code that does not work? Otherwise, this format of question does not meet SO requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, pure WPF implemenation could work like this:

View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="PartOne" Grid.Column="0" Background="Red"/>
        <Grid x:Name="PartTwoContainer" Grid.Column="1">
            <!--PartTwoControl is just UserControl without any special logic in it-->
            <local:PartTwoControl x:Name="PartTwo" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And some logic for it:

```
private const int MaxXToPopup = 300;
private Window _popup;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged( SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo )
{
    if ( ShouldDisplayInPopup() )
    {
        DetachPartTwo();
        OpenPopup();
    }
    else if ( ShouldDisplayInGrid() )
    {
        ClosePopup();
        ShowPartTwo();
    }

    base.OnRenderSizeChanged( sizeInfo );
}

private void ClosePopup()
{
    _popup.Content = null;
    _popup.Close();
    _popup = null;
}

private void OpenPopup()
{
    _popup = new Window {Content = PartTwo};
    _popup.Show();
}

private void ShowPartTwo()
{
    PartTwoContainer.Children.Add( PartTwo );
}

private void DetachPartTwo()
{
    PartTwoContainer.Children.Remove( PartTwo );
}

private bool ShouldDisplayInGrid()
{
    return _popup != null && RenderSize.Width > MaxXToPopup;
}

private bool ShouldDisplayInPopup()
{
    return _popup == null && RenderSize.Width < MaxXToPopup;
}
```